# How do I exclude the App_Data folder when publishing an Azure Web App in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: azure, publish, rider

I am publishing an application to an Azure Web App using the Azure - Publish Web App option in the JetBrains Rider configurations. When I publish the app I want it to not include the App_Data folder, but I cannot see an option to do this.

I've tried editing the .csproj file to add the attributes there to not include this folder in the published project, but the Azure publish profile seems to ignore this. I've also downloaded the publish profile from Azure but I cannot see how to then update that profile on Azure once it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to exclude the App_Data directory from your Rider project is to Exclude it like below:-

[image]

Another option is to directly remove the File from Advanced Tools > Kudu > Tools > Zip push Deploy > And Delete the File from there directly like below:-

[image]

One more option is to Enter Powershell or Debug console in Kudu and run below command to remove the Directory:-

```
rm App_Data
```

[image]

Also, In Azure Web app **AppData Temporary file is mapped to - %SYSTEMDRIVE%\local\AppData** on local machine.

***Refer this [Document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) for more information on Temporary Files including AppData.***